# Zookeeper + Solrcloud create collection using given configuration

Tags: search, indexing, solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am working on a project (with no documentation) which uses Zookeeper + Solrcloud and I am trying to run it only on my laptop for now (a Windows machine). 
I have installed Solr (5.0.0) and Zookeeper (3.4.8).
I have the Solr configuration files ( solrconfig.xml, schema.xml, etc.) in a folder in my filesystem (D:/mySolrConfiguration/). 
So I start Zookeeper and Solr and after that I run the command zkCli as follows:

```
zkcli.bat -zkhost localhost:2181 -cmd upconfig -confdir D:/mySolrConfiguration -confname my-config
```

Then I go to Solr and I try to create a new collection based on my configuration (my-conf), but Solr complains saying "*No config set found to associate with the collection*"
In order to create the collection I hit the following URL in the browser:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=myCollection&collection.configname=my-config&numShards=1
```

I tried also to use linkconfig just before the collection creation as follows:

```
zkcli.bat -zkhost localhost:2181 -cmd linkconfig -collection myCollection -confname my-config
```

But it does not change the outcome.
In the past I was also able to create a configuration, but I cannot see it in any folder is Solr, and there is a collection based on this configuration.
But, if I try to create a new collection based on that configuration I get the same error as above "*No config set found to associate with the collection*".
Did anybody have any similar issue with Solr+Zookeeper in the past? 
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "collection.configName=" instead. The uppercase N is apparently important.